# How to insert into pandas dataframe by alphabetical order of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, insert, insertion-sort

Now I have this:

```
#old df:

bar foo
1   a
3   b
5   z
```

I want to insert a line [6,"d"], so the df becomes:

```
#new df:

bar foo
1   a
3   b
6   d
5   z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `append`

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame([[6,"d"]],columns=df.columns)).sort_values('foo').reset_index(drop=True)
Out[46]: 
   bar foo
0    1   a
1    3   b
2    6   d
3    5   z
```

Also `np.searchsorted` is to find the index order of inserted value in original df

```
pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([[6,"d"]],columns=df.columns,index=np.searchsorted(df.foo,['d'])-1)]).sort_index()
Out[69]: 
   bar foo
0    1   a
1    3   b
1    6   d
2    5   z
```